# Set and call a variable in HTML (potentially including javascript) in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

[image]

I have a HTML code in Django, if certain conditions are met I want to set the colour of a div container. As can be seen in between the script tags, if one condition is met the colour should be set to success, if another is met the colour should be set to danger, then later on in the code in the div class description where I have put (colour) is where this variable should be called. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Django just sees this: `var colour = 'success'` as text when it renders the template, i.e: your variable declarations are read by the client, not Django.

Instead, write that logic directly where you need it. The logic here is even simple enough that a simple ternary statement will do:

```
<div class=bg-{{ 'success' if Post.temperature > threshold.temperature else 'danger' }}>
```

For more complex logic, I'd recommend looking into [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/), which you'd use like so:

```
<!-- template file (.html) -->
<div class=bg-{% get_colour_for_post Post threshold %}>
```

```py
# template tag definition (.py)
@register.simple_tag
def get_colour_for_post(post, threshold):
    return (
        'success'
        if Post.temperature > threshold.temperature
        else 'danger'
    )
```